# Open and Closet set in relative topology at the same time

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Hey I was reading through my notes and I seem to have missed the lecture where our teacher introduced us to relative topology. I understand the basics of it but I can't get over the fact that a set can be closed and open at the same time in relative topology. Could you maybe send me some picture where it can be seen? I understand when the set is union of 2 sets and one of them is open I can make it open and closed in relative topology in C but what if it's just a subset of a set? Like in the following picture how exactly do i make the set B to be open and closed in A?
[image: Image of nested subsets]

Answer (score 0):

In a topological space $X$, there are two sets that are always both open and closed, namely $X$ and $\varnothing$.

If you want to see more *clopen* sets (as they are affectionately called), consider $X=[0,1]\cup[2,3]$ with the topology induced by $\Bbb R$. $[0,1]$ is both closed and open in $X$.

A more general setting where clopen sets are important is in the definition of connected spaces: a space $X$ is *connected* if, for any nonempty, clopen set $A\subseteq X$, $A=X$. Thus a non-connected space contains a non-trivial clopen set, like in the previous example ($[0,1]\cup[2,3]$ is clearly not connected, for the intuitive definition).

---

Let $B\subseteq A$ be two sets. Define $\tau$ the topology on $A$ with only four open sets: $\tau:=(\varnothing,B,A\setminus B,A)$. $\tau$ is a topology: it contains $\varnothing$ and $A$, and is stable by countable unions and finite intersections. Moreover, $B$ is clopen in $A$.

Any refinement of $\tau$, i.e. any topology $\tau'\supseteq\tau$, will also have $B$ as a clopen set.

Comment: Thanks for this. I already knew about the fact that i can make clopen sets thanks to union of two set, was just hoping I could get some picture in 2D because I'm not sure how it works if there was a subset in a set. Is there a way that such a subset can be clopen ? For me it seems like it can't.

Comment: What do you mean by subset? $[0,1]$ is a subset of $[0,1]\cup[2,3]$.

Comment: I added a construction for any $B\subseteq A$, if that may interest you.

Answer (score 0):

Given that all non-empty non-singleton sets are the union of two disjoint sets (just take any proper non-empty subset and its complement), I guess what you mean is that the set $A$ is connected (that is, it is not the union of two *separated* subsets).

But in that case, the only subsets of $A$ that are both closed and open (or clopen, in short) in the relative topology are the empty set and $A$. Indeed, it is the *definition* of a connected space that the only clopen sets are the empty set and the full space.

On the other hand, it does not matter whether one of the connected components of $A$ is open in the full space $C$. If the set $A$ is disconnected, then every connected component of $A$ is clopen in the relative topology.

Comment: Example: $C=\Bbb R$ and $A=[0,1)\cup (1,2]$ and $B=(1,2].$ Neither $A$ nor $B$ is open nor closed in $C$ but $B$ is open-and-closed in $A,$ with $A\ne B\ne \emptyset.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: But $A$ is not connected.